# Visual studio symbol that adds breakpoints when I click it

Tags: visual-studio

What is this symbol on the left side of the code window? When I press it, a breakpoint appears. Left clicking does nothing. I accidentally added it when I miss pressed shortcut.

How do I get rid of it?

[This one](https://i.stack.imgur.com/efvf5.png)

Comment: Bookmark --> Edit|Bookmarks|Toggle.

Comment: That's called a bookmark

Comment: Bookmark: https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=alefragnani.Bookmarks